# Passing props to component in react router

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal that I'd like to place a dynamic nested view in. I figure a good way to do this is to use `Switch` like so

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/modal/slide-1" component={ Widget1 }
    <Route path="/modal/slide-2" component={ Widget2 }
  </Switch>
</div>
```

I would like to pass some props to these components as I would normally in React

```
<Widget1
  prop1="Some Value"
  prop2="Some Other Value"
/>
```

Eventually I'll be moving to store/fetch these properties in the state, but given the current implementation can properties be included when defining a Switch `component`?

Comment: why do you have `patch` it should be `path`

Comment: @Omar typo, thank you

Comment: let us know if you any issue with that.

Comment: @MayankShukla no issue, I didn't find this question initially. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
 <Route
  path={"/modal/slide-1"}
  render={() => (
   <Widget1 prop1={this.state.prop1} />
  )}
 />
```

Render allows you to pass any props to the component you are rendering.